# MySQL SELECT with left join returns null on values from joined table

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have two simple tables, `programs` and `seasons`:

```
programs
| id | season_id | title     |
| 1  | 1         | Program 1 |
| 2  | 1         | Program 2 |
| 3  | 2         | Program 3 |

seasons
| id | season   |
| 1  | Season 1 |
| 2  | Season 2 |
```

Nothing super fancy really, so now I run the following:

```
SELECT
    programs.title, seasons.season 
FROM 
    programs 
LEFT JOIN seasons ON programs.season_id = seasons.id;
```

Leaving me with an expected result of:

```
| title     | season   |
| Program 1 | Season 1 |
| Program 2 | Season 1 |
| Program 3 | Season 2 |
```

However the actual result is as follows:

```
| title     | season   |
| Program 1 | NULL     |
| Program 2 | NULL     |
| Program 3 | NULL     |
```

What is causing this and how to remedy?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is the missing "s" in `season.id` of the `JOIN` a typo? `LEFT JOIN seasons ON programs.season_id = seasons.id;`

Comment: Ow yeah, typo indeed. Sorry. Obviously mysql will give a column not known error when I do that :P

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `seasons` DB actually has the data you've shown?

Comment: Yes, "select * from seasons;" would return 2 rows.

Comment: I am still absolutely clueless as to what cause this weird behavior and have now even gone as far as flat out deleting the database in question, rebuild it via migrations, repopulated it and now the query is behaving as expected.

Is there anything in database/server settings that can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the table structure you have given it should be seasons.season and not seasons.name

Comment: Typo, I had 'name' in the example first and then renamed it to 'season' and missed that one. Issue is not column naming or anything, MySQL will properly tell me to F off if I make typos in column names. It is just that NULL result.